# Atualização de Combobox vinculado ao Binding

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

Estou trabalhando com o padrão `MVVM`, até ai tudo bem, tenho uma classe `PessoaViewlModel`.

Nela eu possuo uma propriedade `IEnumerable<Municipio> Municipios`, no qual me apresenta todos os municipios, de acordo com a `UF(Unidade federativa Selecionada)`.

Quando inicializo WPF de cadastro de pessoa, ele carrega os municipios, porém depois de inicializado passo o comando para que na lista estejam apenas os municipios que correspondem a UF. Na minha propiedade `Municipios` de `PessoaViewModel` fica correto, porém os items no combobox não segue fiel as informações existentes em `Municipios` ao qual o `combobox`  se encontra vinculado com o binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui, resolver o problema, na verdade estava trabalhando com o frmaework MvvmMicro, mudei para o Mvvm light toolkit e funcionou normalmente.
Resaltando que todas as dicas que me deram tentei e não funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ObservableCollection<Municipio>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms668604%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) no lugar do `IEnumerable<Municipio>`.
Sempre que um elemento entra o sai ou dai lista é gerada uma notificação, fazendo a tela modificar os elementos delas.

Não crie um novo objeto, pois assim ira perder a ligação, a não ser que a sua classe implemente a interface [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e você tenha a propriedade

```c#
ObservableCollection<Municipio> _municipios;
public ObservableCollection<Municipio> Municipios
{
    get { return _municipios; }
    set 
    {
        if(_municipios != value) 
        {
            _municipios = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Municipios"));
        }
    }
}
```

Desta forma você pode ainda utilizar o `IEnumerable<Municipio>` porém não funcionará se você adicionar alguma novo elemento na lista.